# What would you call a person or people who does not know your language in either of the scenario

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

What would you call a person or people who does not know your language in either of the scenario whether

> you (as a tourist, as an expatriate or on business) are in their (as a citizen) homeland

or

> they (as a tourist, as an expatriate or on business) are in your (as a citizen) homeland.

Comment: I’d use the term ***foreigner***

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for people ("their" in your first example) who don't happen to know the language of some random other person ("you" in your first example). You'd be hard pressed to find anyone who understands every possible foreign language.

Comment: Is this just a complicated way of asking "what would you call someone who does not speak the same language as you" which would apply whatever context you were in ?  I don't know a one word term for "person who doesn't speak my language from a country other than my own" -- but it might help others if that's what you are looking for

Comment: @Jim lots of foreigners DO speak your langauge

Comment: Bit shorter might be "language barrier" is a euphemism for "we couldn't speak each other's language nor did we have another language we shared to speak in."

Comment: The Question has no meaning because there is no comparison because context really is all.

In your first example, the other people would be "natives" or “locals”…

In your second example, the other people would be “foreigners” or “visitors”…

None of them could ever be expected to share or even understand anything about you, including your language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are specific epithets that could be used with some specific countries and with some specific circumstances, but in general:

First scenario - general "a Native (local)" - or probably refer to them by the country one is in (i.e. French, German, Korean etc.).

Second scenario - general "Foreign (visitor)" - not knowing circumstances. Or by the perceived origin of whatever language you thinks they do speak.